# Floyds Triangle with a sorted array (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm

Say I have a sorted list of [1,2,3,4,5,6] (although this list might be much bigger)

I want to make a Floyd's triangle like this:

1

23

456

With a nested array like this: [[1],[2,3],[4,5,6]]

I am working with nested loops but am stuck.
Most solutions I have found require a size as input for the triangle, which I think in this scenario would be the length of the list of numbers? I am not sure.

```
pyramid=[]
pyramid_line = [numbers[0]]

pyramid.append(pyramid_line)
print(pyramid)

size = len(numbers)

for i in range(1,size-1):

    pyramid_line=[]
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        pyramid_line.append(numbers[i])
        while len(pyramid_line) <= i:
            pyramid_line.append(numbers[i+1])
    
    pyramid.append(pyramid_line)
print(pyramid)
```

This gives an output of

```
[['1'], ['2', '3'], ['3', '4', '4', '3'], ['4', '5', '5', '5', '4', '4'], ['5', '6', '6', '6', '6', '5', '5', '5']]
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far, what the results were, and how it is different from what you are expecting, or which part you don't understand.

Comment: Added code attempt

Answer (score 1):

In reviewing your current code and the alleged requirement of not entering a size, following is a refactored version of your code that you might use as food for thought.

```
user_input = list(input("Enter list: ").split(",")) 

valid = False

# Check that the list length is a proper size to create a triangle

for x in range(0,100):
    if ((x * x + x) / 2 == len(user_input)):
        valid = True
        break

if not valid:
    print("Improper number of elements to produce a triangle")
    exit(1)

x = 0
y = 1
master_list = []

while True:             # Build the nested inner list elements and append them into the master list
    inner_list = []
    for i in range(x, (x + y)):
        inner_list.append(user_input[i])
    x += y
    y += 1
    master_list.append(inner_list)

    if x >= len(user_input):
        break

print("Resulting list:", master_list)

for i in master_list:
    for j in i:
        print(j, end="")
    print(" \n")
```

This approach requires a user to enter a list as a comma delimited list, which is then checked for a proper size to produce a proper triangle (e.g. size of 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, and so forth).

If the length is valid, then increasingly larger nested lists are built and then appended into a master list.

Following was a sample test of this at the terminal.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Floyd$ python3 Triangle.py 
Enter list: 1,2,3,4,5,6
Resulting list: [['1'], ['2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
1 

23 

456
```

As I said, food for thought.  As always, I recommend referencing Python tutorial literature, especially in this case as it pertains to lists.

Answer (score 1):

Since NoDakker already provided a great answer, I'll instead offer an interesting recursive variant.

The idea behind the below code is that the number of elements in each row is the same as the number of the row. This is why `newRow` is defined as the array from 0 to current row size, and each time the array shrinks to hold elements from the current row number to the end. Meanwhile, the row number increments by one each time the function is called recursively.

```py
def makeTriangleRecursive(arr, row=1):
    if not arr:
        return []
    newRow = arr[:row]
    return [newRow] + makeTriangleRecursive(arr[row:], row + 1)
```

Usage:

```py
makeTriangleRecursive(list(range(1, 15+1)))
```

Again, this is just an interesting little piece of code, and again, it is recursive. So it shoudn't be used in production unless you can guarantee the size of the array will always be relatively small. As a reference, my laptop started struggling at arrays of size 200000.

Comment: That's a nice twist on the theme.  There's always many ways to get to a solution.

Comment: @NoDakker Thanks; and your input validation logic is a nice touch :)

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm concerned only with determining the size of the triangle, which I assume is it's height or number of rows.

Let

- `n` be the size of the given array (known) and
- `m` be the size of the triangle (to be determined).

The number of elements in the triangle is seen to equal

```
1 + 2 + ... + m
```

This is a simple algebraic sum whose total equals

```
m*(m+1)/2
```

By definition, it equals `n`:

```
n = m*(m+1)/2
```

Solving for `m` we have the quadratic:

```
m^2 + m - 2*n = 0
```

whose roots equal

```
m = (-b +- sqrt(b^2 - 4ac))/2
```

where

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = -2*n
```

so

```
m = (-1 +- sqrt(1+8*n))/2
```

---

Let's take the example of `n = 6`:

```
m = (-1 +- sqrt(49))/2 = (-1 +- 7)/2
```

We are only interested in the positive root:

```
m = 6/2 = 3
```

So if the given array contains `6` elements the triangle has `3` rows, each element below being an index into the given array:

```
0
1 2
3 4 5
```

---

Similarly, if `n = 15`

```
m = (-1 +- sqrt(1+8*15))/2 = (-1 +- sqrt(121))/2 = (-1 +- 11)/2
```

Taking the positive root,

```
m = 5
```

So if the given array contains `15` elements the triangle has `5` rows, each element below being an index into the given array:

```
0
1  2
3  4  5
6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14
```

---

Suppose now `n = 19`, then

```
m = (-1 +- sqrt(-1 + (8*19)))/2
  = (-1 +- sqrt(151))/2
  = (-1 +- 1.29)/2
```

So `m` will not be an integer, meaning the given array cannot produce a Floyd's triangle.